# "Attention Something went wrong" on backend product page

Tags: product, error, page

This error shows up everytime I click on a product. The product loads and saves properly. It began to appear before I updated to 2.1 and still continues to appear after the update.

[error http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error.png](http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error.png)

This is what I got from Chrome Inspect:
[error http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error1.png](http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error1.png)
When I clicked the link:

> 1 exception(s):
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Object DOMDocument should be created.
>   [error http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error2.png](http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error2.png)

This was in var/report

> a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:5384:"#0 /home/ttothef1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()

[error http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error3.png](http://ttothefourth.com/errorimg/error3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the "review" module disabled.

Enable it, only fix for now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be enough if you delete the var folder, delete `pub/static/adminhtml` and then run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your terminal to **enable all** modules and to do the deploy again:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;

mage module:enable --all

mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```